# Verification of sequence result

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence

Is it true that if a real sequence $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ has an infimum but no convergent subsequences then the infimum must be the minimum as well?

Secondly, can it be proved that the sequence defined as $x_n = (-1)^{n} + \sqrt{n}$ is a sequence which has no convergent subsequence?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that what an infimum is?

Comment: @user166967 Not necessarily, the infimum of a sequence can exist without the existence of a minimum.

Comment: You mean the infimum doesn't have to be a member of the sequence?

Comment: Since $x_n\rightarrow\infty$, $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow\infty$ for any subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This is indeed the case. Try to prove it by assuming the sequence has a infimum that is *not* a minimum as well, and show that the sequence has a convergent subsequence.